# Exception in thread “main” java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 error in Java

Tags: java

Can someone tell me what changes has to be done to get rid of this error and why is this happening?

```
public class Gambler { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int stake = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);    // gambler's stating bankroll
        int goal  = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);    // gambler's desired bankroll
        int T     = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);    // number of trials to perform

        int bets = 0;        // total number of bets made
        int wins = 0;        // total number of games won

        // repeat T times
        for (int t = 0; t < T; t++) {

            // do one gambler's ruin simulation
            int cash = stake;
            while (cash > 0 && cash < goal) {
                bets++;
                if (Math.random() < 0.5) cash++;     // win $1
                else                     cash--;     // lose $1
            }
            if (cash == goal) wins++;                // did gambler go achieve desired goal?
        }

        // print results
        System.out.println(wins + " wins of " + T);
        System.out.println("Percent of games won = " + 100.0 * wins / T);
        System.out.println("Avg # bets           = " + 1.0 * bets / T);
    }

}
```

Comment: Probabaly because there isn't 3 arguments in the array `args`... Did you even bother to check?

Comment: Which line? When you're asking for help it's a good idea to give as much helpful information as you can.

Comment: 4th line int stake.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int stake = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);    // gambler's stating bankroll
int goal  = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);    // gambler's desired bankroll
int T     = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);    // number of trials to perform
```

You probably want to verify the number of arguments you are receiving.

You probably want to take a look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html